# Bean name is ambiguous matches same bean twice

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use spring-data-jpa and spring-data-mongodb. On deploy, several of my repositories deploy, until one (a random one each time) fails to deploy with an error of

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414:   Bean name is ambiguous. Name    za.co.knonchalant.dead.dao.repositories.UserRepository resolves to beans: 
  - CdiRepositoryBean: type='za.co.knonchalant.dead.dao.repositories.UserRepository', qualifiers=[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()],
  - CdiRepositoryBean: type='za.co.knonchalant.dead.dao.repositories.UserRepository', qualifiers=[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]"}}
```

It seems to be matching the same interface twice - any idea of what might be happening?

The `UserRepository` interface is

```
public interface UserRepository extends LocationRepository<User> { }
```

And `LocationRepository` is a general root interface for locations, that looks like

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface LocationRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, String> {
    List<T> findByPositionWithin(Circle c);

    List<T> findByPositionNear(Point p, Distance distance);

    List<T> findByPositionWithin(Box b);
}
```

My configuration, which I'm not overly confident in, is

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CdiConfig {
    @Produces
    @Dependent
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mongo-ogm")
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    public
    @Bean
    Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new Mongo("localhost");
    }

    @Produces
    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "mydatabase");
    }
}
```

Along with a `persistence.xml` as per the following - is this the right provider?

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mongo-ogm" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="database"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="MONGODB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: may be it will be a good idea if you could include the code for your UserRepository.

Comment: Are you using `spring-data-jpa` and `spring-data-mongodb`?. maybe `spring-data-jpa` is generating a `Jpa Repository Bean` and `spring-data-mongodb` a `MonogRepository` Bean?. Could you add your configuration?

Comment: I am - I'll add the configuration as soon as I get near the code, I would need both of those libraries in this case though wouldn't I?

Comment: @Pau Added the configuration I'm using.

Comment: Are you trying to use in a CDI environment (i.e. without a Spring container) or in a Spring environment? If the former then remove the Spring specific annotations from the CdiConfig class.

Comment: I am seeing same issue with WELD CDI environment, is this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine both libraries have the same beans so you need add provided scope into your Maven pom.xml for one of those libraries. Looks like Spring is finding the same bean in multiple places.

Comment: That bean is one of my own, so it only exists in my data layer (which is only included once)